# Is it possible to run an Oozie Spark Action without specifying inputDir & outputDir

Tags: oozie, mapr, oozie-workflow

According to https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters we know ..

```
When submitting a workflow job for the workflow definition above, 3 workflow job properties must be specified:

jobTracker:
inputDir:
outputDir:
```

I have a PySpark script that has specified input & output locations in the script itself. I don't need and want an `inputDir` and `outputDir` in my workflow XML.  When running my PySpark script via Oozie, I get this error message.

```
WARN ParameterVerifier:523 - SERVER[<my_server>] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] The application does not define formal parameters in its XML definition

 WARN JobResourceUploader:64 - SERVER[<my_server>] Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.

2018-05-24 11:52:29,844  WARN JobResourceUploader:171 - SERVER[<my_server>] No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
```

Based on https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/util/ParameterVerifier.java , my first warning is caused by the fact that I dont have a "inputDir"

```
else {
                // Log a warning when the <parameters> section is missing
                XLog.getLog(ParameterVerifier.class).warn("The application does not define formal parameters in its XML "
                        + "definition");
            }
```

Can I get around this at all ?

Update -- my XML structure

```
<action name="spark-node">
      <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1" >
         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
         <configuration>
             <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
             </property>
             <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>${inputDir}</value>
             </property>
             <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>${outputDir}</value>
             </property>
         </configuration>
         <master>yarn-master</master>
         <!-- <mode>client</mode>  -->
         <name>oozie_test</name>
         <jar>oozie_test.py</jar>
          <spark-opts>--num-executors 1 --executor-memory 10G --executor-cores  1 --driver-memory 1G</spark-opts>
      </spark>
      <ok to="end" />
      <error to="fail" />
   </action>
```

Comment: Which action type are you using to run the pySpark script (like ssh action/spark action)?

Comment: <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1" >

Comment: Could you please share complete action definition? Are you missing '            <jar>[SPARK DEPENDENCIES JAR / PYTHON FILE]</jar>' parameter ? 
The spark action does not have 'inputDir' and 'outputDir' elements as per schema definition. Please refer below link.
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

Comment: fair point. I pasted my spark action defnition. It has a "jar" parameter. I also have a "lib" directory for zip files for pyspark and python. Seems like my "jar" is not being recognized even though it's in the XML